# Add values to multiple objects at once via a html form in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

i got some problems with the code shown below! i want to create a view which shows a list of usernames (as seen in the @participate in the user_weight method). next to the names i want to provide a dropdown select where you can assign a value from 1 to 5 to a certain user.

right now i'm totally stuck! the view only shows my approach to the problem which isn't working at all ... (:attendee & :user_weight are just placeholders right now)

if i try it out the way it is i get a: "undefined method `merge' for [["1", 1], ["2", 2], ["3", 3], ["4", 4], ["5", 5]]:Array" error

hope that anyone has an idea!

**files:**

user_weight.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @users, :url => {action: "create_user_weight"} do |f| %>

<ul>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <li> <%= user.username %> <%= f.select(:attendee, :user_weight, [['1', 1], ['2', 2], ['3', 3], ['4', 4], ['5', 5]]) %> </li>
  <% end %>
  <p>
    <%= button_to "Select User Weight", action: "create" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

schema.rb

```
  create_table "attendees", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "task_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.boolean  "participate"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_weight"
  end

  create_table "friendships", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "friend_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "selectdates", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "task_date"
    t.boolean  "participate"
    t.integer  "attendee_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "task_id"
  end

  create_table "tasks", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "text"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "participate"
    t.date     "meeting_date"
    t.time     "meeting_start_time"
    t.time     "meeting_end_time"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password_hash"
    t.string   "password_salt"
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "company"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

tasks_controller.rb

```
  def select_user
    @user = User.all
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end

  def participate
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.users << User.all

    @attendees = Attendee.where(User_id: params[:user_checkbox])
    Attendee.transaction do
      @attendees.each do |attendee|
        attendee.update_attributes!(participate: true)
      end
    end

    redirect_to :action => 'user_weight', :id => @task
  end


  def user_weight
    @participants = Attendee.where(participate: true, task_id: params[:id])
    @users = @participants.map { |p| User.find_by id: p.user_id }.to_set.to_a
  end
```

attendee.rb

```
class Attendee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :user
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendees
  has_many :tasks, :through => :attendees

  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships

  has_many :selectdates
end
```

task.rb

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendees
  has_many :users, :through => :attendees
  has_many :selectdates, dependent: :destroy
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  #match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)', via: [:get, :post]

  get 'tasks/new'
  get 'tasks/create'
  get 'tasks/select_date'
  get 'tasks/user_weight', :as => "user_weight"
  get 'tasks/select_user', :as => "select_user"

  match "tasks/participate" => "tasks#participate", :via => :post
  match "tasks/create_date" => "tasks#create_date", :via => :patch, :as => "create_date"
  match "tasks/create_user_weight" => "tasks#create_user_weight", :via => :patch, :as => "create_user_weight"


  resources :tasks

  get "logout" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "logout"
  get "login" => "sessions#new", :as => "login"
  get "signup" => "users#new", :as => "signup"
  get "account" => "sessions#account", :as => "account"

  get "addfriends" => "friendships#new", :as => "addfriends"

  resources :users do
    collection do
      update 'multiple_update'
    end
  end



  resources :sessions
  resources :friendships



  root 'welcome#index'
```

Comment: Which line of the above produces that error?

Comment: <li> <%= user.username %> <%= f.select(:attendee, :user_weight, [['1', 1], ['2', 2], ['3', 3], ['4', 4], ['5', 5]]) %> </li>

Comment: in the user_weight.html.erb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

form_for won't know how to properly process an array of users.  I would use a form_tag for this.  You'll need a custom action in your users controller.  I'd suggest setting it up like so:

```
#routes
resources :users do
  collection do
    update 'multiple_update'
  end
end

#controller
#expects params like {:users => {123 => {:weight => 3}, 456 => {:weight => 4}} 
#where 123 and 456 are user ids
def multiple_update
  @users = []
  params[:users].each do |id, attributes|
    if user = User.find_by_id(id)
      if user.update_attributes(attributes)
        @users << user
      end
    end
  end
end

#view 
<% form_tag multiple_update_users_path, :method => :update do %>
  <ul>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <li> <%= user.username %> <%= select_tag "users[#{user.id}][weight]", options_for_select([['1', 1], ['2', 2], ['3', 3], ['4', 4], ['5', 5]], user.weight) %> </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <%= submit_tag "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks for your awesome answer! but now i'm getting an "undefined method `update' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x000001027377d0>" error... any ideas?

Comment: seems to be a problem with the line: "update 'multiple_update'" in the routes.rb - btw i'm using rails 4.1.6

Comment: hmm, sorry, that was just from memory...according to this page http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html that looks like the right syntax for defining a collection route.  Their examples don't include an `update` but i'd expect it to be the same syntax as their `get` example.  Can you try changing the route to `post` instead of `update` and then remove `:method => :update` from the form?  (so the form defaults back to submitting a post request)